# How can I update the user password in Selenium-Grid-Extras?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

Can anyone link me to a good Selenium-Grid-Extras guide?  I have it installed, and need to customize it.  Specifically, I need to update the credentials, and reboot settings.  When I go to my link: http://XX.XX.XX.XX:3000/user_auto_logon, I can see the settings, but I don't know how to change them.  Also, when I open my selenium_grid_extras_config.json I don't see a section that has any of this information to update.  Also, even if I did find a section in the selenium_grid_extras_config.json, how would I update the password for the existing username... I'm sure it's not going to be displayed in plain text.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Shawn McCarthy. This solved my problem:

*If you want, you can just delete the selenium_grid_extras_config.json file, and rerun the jar file and it will go through the FirstTimeRunConfig again.*

*You should be able to pass in the username and password to the endpoint as well, http://XX.XX.XX.XX:3000/user_auto_logon?username=YOUR_USER&password=YOUR_PASSWORD*

*You can check out the /api endpoint to see all the possible endpoints, and the accepted parameters (and which ones are required or not). Usually with no parameters, it does a get current status/value.*

Thanks Shawn!